# How to create an array list of an array

Tags: java

How to implement an arraylist of an array
My code:

```
  ArrayList<Arrays> s = new ArrayList<Arrays>();
  int[] A = new int[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     A[i]=in.nextInt();
  s.add(A); //give me an error
  int x = s.get(0)[1] // getting the first element of an Array A
```

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: Or just create an `ArrayList` or `ArrayList`s...`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and get all the benefits without all the hassle..

Comment: why do you need an arraylist of an array?

Comment: you given some wqrong code...theres no any method like srraylist.get

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

`List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();`
When you do a `get()` operation, remember that you will get an integer array and not an int.

Usage :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int[] arr = {1,2,3};
    list.add(arr);
    System.out.println(list.get(0)[1]);
  }
```

Another approach is to use :`Arrays.asList()`. This will return an *almost immutable* List with a single element which is an array.

Your problem : `Arrays` is a helper class which supports operations on array data structure. So, essentially, your *assumption* that `Arrays` can contain any array-type is wrong.

Comment: do not you think you need more than this to help the op understand its issue?

Comment: @KickButtowski - what more can/should I add?

Comment: you could break it down more since the op wants to have an arraylist of an array? lol!!!

Answer (score 0):

Understand this code first.. You'll be able to resolve Your problem Yourself...

```
private static void arrayListOfString() {
    //List of String arrays
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] arr2 = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    list.add(arr1);
    list.add(arr2);
    //printing list of String arrays in the ArrayList
    for (String[] strArr : list) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    List<int[]> s = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter limit: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] A = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        System.out.print((i+1)+" element: ");
        A[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
    s.add(A);
    //s.get(0)[0]; first element
    //s.get(0)[1]; second element
    //s.get(0)[2]; third element
    //so on
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        System.out.print(s.get(0)[i]+" ");
```